# Pass by Reference and Memory Usage

Tags: c++, function, reference

When passing arguments by reference in C++, how does it treat variables that are defined based on one of those references. For instance, I created a function `MyFunc1` and then an alternate function `MyFunc2` that tries to implement the same functionality. In the second, there is a `y` that is defined in terms of `x`. Is `y` also treated like a reference in terms of the amount of memory used?

```
int MyFunc1(const int &x, const int &a, const int &times_minus_one=1) {
    if (times_minus_one == 1) {
        return -x * a;
    } else {
        return x * a;
    }
}
```

and

```
int MyFunc2(const int &x, const int &a, const int &times_minus_one=1) {
    int y = x;
    if (times_minus_one == 1) {
        y = y * -1;
    }
    return y * a;
}
```

Comment: No, `y` is an `int`. It says so here: `int y = ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way you've defined y in MyFunc2, y is a copy of the original variable. Here the copy is being instantiated on the stack and will occupy sizeof(y) memory on the stack.

If for example you'd defined y as `const auto& y = x;` then y would be a reference which is simply the size of a pointer.

Comment: That second line is exactly what I was going to follow up with the @juanchopanza about. It seems though that when I do the if statement, I get errors because I set `y` as `const`.

Comment: I would add that as @Don Reba pointed out, `y` takes memory only theoretically. A good optimizer would likely keep `y` in a register which would mean it would occupy any memory. I didn't mention this in my answer because I assumed you were using an int as a general example for larger classes (say things too big to be held in a register).

Comment: Yes, I was using it as an example of something larger. Are you aware of any websites or books where your point about the register is explained in more detail?

Comment: @John Frankly, I'm not aware of good resource. That was just the kind of thing I learned a little at a time here and there. 

Obviously, the ultimate source is the standard itself. Which does call out all the rules, but in a very terse and hard to read way. 

For more general information, the book "Efficient C++" is a good resource.

Comment: Thanks. I've got a copy of that, but I've only made a little way into it. I think it assumes a level of C++ understanding that I'm still working to attain.

Answer (score 2):

The `y` in your code is just an integer to which you assign the value of `x`. It may or may not use any memory — the standard does not specify. As for memory footprint of references in general — they usually behave the same as pointers.

Comment: What @Don Reba is pointing out is that y could actually be held in a register it may not actually have a real memory address assigned. This is true.